# How to create infinite loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a slider which has a "Next Button". I want to make my slider infinite. Right now when I click "Next Button" it will show the next slide but when I reach the last slide and click the "Next Button" the slides won't go back to its first image.

Here's what I did:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.learnAnimals = function(options) {
    var $animals = this;
    /* Next Button */
    $animals.find('.next').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          var index = $('.next').index(this);
          $animals.find(".curr_animal").fadeOut('slow');
          $animals.find(".curr_animal").removeClass('curr_animal');
          if (index <= 6) {
            $animals.find(".info-wrapper").eq(index + 1).fadeIn('slow');
            $animals.find(".info-wrapper").eq(index + 1).addClass('curr_animal');

            /* Hide inactive divs */
            $animals.find("div.info-wrapper").not(".curr_animal").hide();
            return $animals;
          };
        })(jQuery);
        if (index == 0) {
          $animals.find(".info-wrapper").eq(index).addClass('curr_animal');
        }
      }


    });
});

/* Hide inactive divs */
$animals.find("div.info-wrapper").not(".curr_animal").hide();
return $animals;
};
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="learn_animal">
  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper  curr_animal">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/100_1793.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/DSC_0002.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/DSC_0014.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/DSC_0016.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/DSC_0019.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row option-wrapper info-wrapper">


    <div class="col-lg-6 clearfix">
      <div class="aging-img">
        <img class="border-image" src="http://mydevwebsites.info/okczookiOS k2/wp-content/themes/okczoo/images/research/gorilla/DSC_0021.JPG" width="818" height="534" alt="Aging" />
        <div class="next-btn clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpp4k4tL/

Comment: `when i reach the last slide and click the "Next Button" the slides won't go back to its first image.` then where it will go ??

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, he want it to go back to the `1st slide` if it's in the last slide now. But with the current code it's not going back to the `1st slide`.

Comment: He mentioned this `when i reach the last slide and click the "Next Button" the slides won't go back to its first image`

Comment: @Kyojimaru is right, that's what i mean. Thanks

Comment: @user2089597, can you provide a working example using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @user2089597 I hardly think infinite loop is the solution for your problem.

Comment: I see you're using the index variable - does this need to be explicitly passed in the function?

    $animals.find('.next').each(function(index){

Comment: I think your title is confusing - some people think you want a code loop that never exits. From what I understand you really want a looping image gallery where you can keep clicking 'next' and when it gets to the last image you can still click next and it will go to the first image as if it's the next one along. As a result the most upvoted answer is the best answer for a completely different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I reach the last slide and click the "Next Button" the slides
>   won't go back to its first image

Try managing index between 0-4 as you have 5 `.row` in your posted html:

```
$animals.find('.next').on('click', function(){
    var index = $('.next').index(this);
    $animals.find(".curr_animal").fadeOut('slow').removeClass('curr_animal');
    index = (index + 1) % 5;
    $animals.find(".info-wrapper").eq(index).fadeIn('slow').addClass('curr_animal');
});
```

*Edited:*

Removed hard coded max index:

```
index = (index + 1) % $('.next').length;
```

Comment: +1, simpler and cleaner code. Here's the working example using your code [http://jsfiddle.net/bn4gn4az/](http://jsfiddle.net/bn4gn4az/)

Comment: @Kyojimaru, credits to you sir for entertaining my question, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arvind, sir tried your answer but this only work for a 5 indexes. some of my slides has 8 indexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to create infinite loops in Javascript. Here are some of them:

1.) You can simply say:

```
while (true) {
    //your code
}
```

True is always going to be true.

2.) As long as another condition is true. (this may be helpful if you intend to terminate the loop at some point.

```
var obj1 = {number:"1"};

while (obj1==obj1)
{
document.write( '1++');
 }
```

3.) You can set a "timer" within a function:

```
function loopFunction(){ setInterval(function () {loopFunction();}, 3000);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following? I added `else` condition to restart the `index` from 0. Let's see if it works:

```
if( index < 4 ){//this assumes that you have 5 elements
    $animals.find( ".info-wrapper" ).eq( index + 1 ).fadeIn( 'slow'    ) ;
    $animals.find( ".info-wrapper" ).eq( index + 1 ).addClass( 'curr_animal' );
    if( index == 0 ){
         $animals.find( ".info-wrapper" ).eq( index ).addClass( 'curr_animal' );
    }
}
else{
    index == 0;
    $animals.find( ".info-wrapper" ).eq( index ).addClass( 'curr_animal' );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, Tried this one, but still it won't go back to the first slide. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user2089597 can you try `if( index < 4 )` or `if( index < 5 )`? how do you know it should 6?

Comment: i use 6 because 1 have two slides, and the other slide has 6 elements

Comment: @user2089597 then you should use `if( index < 5 )`

Comment: actually i have 4 slides in my website and each slides has different numbers of elements. some has 4, some has 5 others has 8